# How to disable only date selection in UIDatePicker not time selection

Tags: iphone, ios, uidatepicker, uidatepickermodetime

I am using UIDatePicker in my app and I want to disable only date selection in it and time selection should not be effected.

Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the `datePickerMode` to `UIDatePickerModeTime`.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
```

Other options are:

```
typedef enum {
   UIDatePickerModeTime,
   UIDatePickerModeDate,
   UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime,
   UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer
} UIDatePickerMode;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
```

by using Attribute inspector in the GUI you could also set it as follows
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the correct answers to set it programmatically, you can also set it on your xib file , in the attributes inspector tab.

Answer (score 0):

Change the UIDatePickerMode from UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime to UIDatePickerModeTime like this...

```
[self.datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
```